# Why: My phone will not install downloded apps. Will not calculate Storge usage % (Audio, Apps, etc.)?

Tags: internal-storage, troubleshooting

My phone **wouldn't install an app** the other day (jefitt) so I tried looking at the internal memory (% usage for Audio, etc.) and it **wouldn't calculate** it (just showed the *calculating* status for 4 or 5 minutes then that detail went away, replaced by just "Internal Storage).

I deleted a bunch of files and then tried again and JeFitt installed. Internal memory was low (about 200 MB of 8 GB free) so I thought maybe it was a bit constipated.

Now it's doing the same thing. Tried installing a couple of different apps with the above symptoms.

What I've tried:

- Deleted files so that I have 1.2 GB free on internal memory, 2+ GB free on SD card.
- Booted into Safe Mode with the same symptoms
- Simple Restart and [Soft Reset](http://support.verizonwireless.com/support/devices/knowledge_base.html/50092) with same symptoms.

This is a Motorola Razr M (Micro) with Android 4.2

Comment: lol, Android's internal memory is "constipated". brilliant! :D oh dear, ok seriously, first thing first, are you rooted? If so, using root explorer or equivalent, you may find a directory called `/data/tombstones` and `/data/anr` in which there could be log files filled up in there, that can be the culprit, it would be safe to delete them.

Comment: I am rooted, but have not installed a custom ROM. And I don't have a /tombestones/ directory on either the SDcard0 (internal mem) or SDcard1 (sd card)

Comment: the directory `/data/tombstones` is on the system partition, not on the sdcard.

Comment: @t0mm13b  Not sure how to get to Tombstones so posting that as a seperate question:http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61624/